# Differentiate between two <span> elements

Tags: jquery, html

So I have two similar dropdown menus, and I managed to get the selector of their content(with the inspector item). They look like this:

[image]

I want the first one to change as the condition is fulfilled. Right now both of them are changing, as the both have the same classname. A screenshot about the inspected element:

[image]

jQuery:

```
$("span.filter-option.pull-left").text(polyline.profile);
```

But these span elements are not even in my html code, so I can't change their class nor ID. So what can I do to get the selector of the specific dropdown that I'm aiming at?

Edit: here is my html:

```
<div id="fc">
            <div id="pr">
                <p id="label">Profile:</p>
                <select class="selectpicker" id ="myselect">
                    <option>trekking</option>
                    <option>fastbike</option>
                    <option>car-fast</option>
                    <option>shortest</option>
                    <option>moped</option>
                    <option>fastbike-lowtraffic</option>
                    <option>fastbike-asia-pacific</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="pr1">
                <p id="label1">Alternatives:</p>
                <select class="selectpicker" id ="alternativeidx">
                    <option>Original</option>
                    <option>First alternative</option>
                    <option>Second alternative</option>
                    <option>Third alternative</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="puttony" onClick="changeSelectedRoute()">Change</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show code for both buttons and spans? Maybe something like $("button[title='trekking'] > span.filter-option.pull-left")

Comment: tried your version, didnt work. edited my question.

Comment: Your new code does not have any span. I meant the code you cannot change and you want to select with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the data-id attribute :

```
$('button[data-id="myselect"]').find('span').text(value);
```

I guess this ID is unique.

Comment: I did it, but then when I want to change the profile the dropdown acts weird: the text is centered in the box, the little arrow-head that aims down disappears, and more importantly, when I select one of the elements from the menu, the box displays the same profile as before, not the newly selected. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Edited with span selector now.

Comment: Thank you, a little bit of change, and it worked out. The final version:
$('button[data-id="myselect"]').find("span.filter-option.pull-left").text(polyline.profile);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the position in the DOM is always going to be the same, you can either use the **[`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)** or **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** JavaScript methods:

```js
var sample1 = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[1];
var sample2 = document.querySelectorAll('span')[1];

console.log(sample1);
console.log(sample2);
```

```html
<span>One</span>
<span>Two</span>
```

Note that both return a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements, so you'll need to access the index. If you're unsure what the index is, you can **loop** over all of the results and check something like the **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** for a specific keyword:

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  if (spans[i].innerHTML == 'Two') {
    console.log(spans[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<span>One</span>
<span>Two</span>
```

The same principle can also be applied in jQuery if need be:

```js
var spans = $('span');

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  if ($(spans[i]).text() == 'Two') {
    console.log($(spans[i]).text());
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>One</span>
<span>Two</span>
```

Hope this helps! :)